# Greeting card font identification

Tags: font-identification

**What is the name of this font?:**

[image]

**Sample used on Whatdafont:**

[image]

Note: I already tried Whatdafont and the results are similar but not hand drawn like in the photo. Also, the capital **I** is not being recognized by the search engine.

Comment: Did you try what the font? or are you just posting that image so others can do it for you?

Comment: @Scott I already tried WDF and the results are similar but not hand drawn like in the photo, 2nd question: no sir, I did it because maybe there is another service like what da font that I don't know.

Comment: @Scott, if you know about another service like WDF, tell me

Comment: Okay, just curious if you had tried WTF. The question didn't state that.

Comment: @Scott, is WDF not WTF.

Comment: I don't know, you used "WDF", not me. The better known site is http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ I don't know where you go the "D"

Comment: @Scott I don't know either, maybe to avoid WTF so funny, XD

Answer (score 2):

### LUELLA:

[image]

*I used this website called: [WhatFontIs](http://www.whatfontis.com/)*

Comment: similar. but not exact.

Comment: @SaturnsEye, is the same font, it looks different because they distorted it using the transform tool.